# Replace string in a 20 gb csv file

Tags: linux, csv, scripting

I have a large csv file (20 GB). In the file I want to replace all occurrences of `\r` with `<br/>`. I am using the following commands to achieve this:

```
sed -i 's/\r/<br\/>/g' data.csv

 perl -i.bak -pe 's/\r/<br\/>/g' data.csv
```

The issue is that both these commands are failing ( resulting file is empty). Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Is your file using Linux line endings (`'\r'`) or other? Have you tried writing `\n` instead of `\r` (the C standard says line endings are automatically converted to `\n`, so that could affect these programs (I know it does vim))? Also, "failing" and "resulting file is empty" are very different.

Comment: Actually the file has both \n and \r . On a smaller file I first replaced all \n with <br/> and still found some new line characters. It is then I replaced \r and it worked. I am not able to do the similar operation on a large file. 

Yes the command didn't fail. It resulted in an empty file

Comment: Ok, so did the file originate from os x or windows or something? You could always try dos2unix and similar commands to fix the line endings. Nevertheless, the unescaped backslash could be a problem as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `sed` command with this one, I just added a `\` to source string, it will make `\` as normal character.

```
sed -i 's/\\r/<br\/>/g' data.csv
```

Also there is another way to do this,

```
tr '\r' '_' data.csv
sed -i 's/_/<br\/>/g' data.csv
```

Comment: but I want \r to be treated as carriage return. The same command works on smaller file. I am not sure, how this will change the output?

Comment: I tried my own file so, answered this here, @user2730428 did you yet tried my answer??

Comment: You sure @user2730428 that your file contain `\r` which you needed to replaced?

Comment: then it's no use of replacing such character which you don't know is present in your file.

Comment: But it shouldn't affect the output right?. Even if the character is not there, I should get the same file as output?

Comment: If there is no `\r` then with what you gonna replace? Running this command is meaningless in such case, and yes the output should be same as well.